# Unable to run Xamarin.UItests on Xcode 10.2

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.uitest, xcode10.2

I’ve faced issue with Xcode 10.2 and Xamarin.UITest. Every time I try to start UITests it throws exception:

> “Unable to determine simulator version for CA82FB2F-CDE5-4083-9718-108A86EFF1B3”

I have only one simulator for this id. How can I fix it?

Some tech info:
Mac os mojave
10.14.4 (18E226)

Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac
Version 8.0.2 (build 23)

Mono Framework MDK
Mono 5.18.1.3 (2018-08/fdb26b0a445) (64-bit)

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 12.8.0.0 (Visual Studio Community)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

Update to Xamarin.UITest v2.2.7.2002-dev

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.UITest/2.2.7.2002-dev

> ### Improvements
>
> - [iOS] Preliminary support for Xcode 10.2

## Explanation

Each time Apple updates Xcode, [Xamarin.UITest](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.UITest/2.2.7.2002-dev) and/or [Xamarin.TestCloudAgent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.TestCloud.Agent/) need to be updated to match the updated APIs in Xcode.

Comment: Typically an exception for this is patch versions of Xcode, such as Xcode 10.2.1. However I don't know if that's always guaranteed to be true; I just know that at least as far back as Xcode 9 I don't think I ever saw a patch version that triggered these types of issues...while minor versions pretty much always have.